# placeholder and text over the icon of a input

Tags: html, css, forms, input, icons

i'm creating a form and I want to put an icon into the input text, but when it comes to preview the text is put over the icon and I don't know how to fix it

the html looks like this

```
 <div id="name"> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nombre"> </div>
```

and the css as well

```
#name{
    float:left;
}
#name input {
  font:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:24px;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  background-color:transparent;
  color:#56828B;
  width:300px;
  height:30px;
  background-image:url(../imgs/nameicon.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color:#56828B;
   padding-left:5px;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need an image for that. Try the method below and the problem will never occur again:

```css
#name {
  font:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:24px;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  border: 5px solid #999;
  color:#56828B;
  width:240px;
  height:30px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
   position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px; /* makes space for the icon */
  
}


#name:after {
  content: '\f095';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #999
  
  }
input:focus, input:active {
  
  outline: 00;
  
  }


#name input {
  border: none!important;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:transparent;
   color:#56828B;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="name"> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nombre"> </div>
```

**Note:** This is just an example, adjust to suit your needs.

[See this tutorial here](http://webdesignsharepoint.com/style-form-elements-with-font-awesome-icons/)